# How do I troubleshoot a 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, http, arduino

I am running a program that reports data about a pump runtime and amps to a server using a POST request to a PHP page. The system is running fine on several Arduino Pro Minis. I am testing it out on a board that I built using a 328 and Arduino Uno bootloader, and of the 4 different POST requests, two work and two fail.

I believe this to be caused by the Arduino poorly forming the POST request, but I have no way to verify this since the Arduino Serial.prints the correct string. If I manually hard code the string, it also works.

I form the data this way:

```
byte runtime = analogRead(A3); // generates random data
float amps = analogRead(A2) / 100;
char cruntime[4]; // create char array for runtime
char camps[5];
dtostrf(runtime, 4, 0, cruntime);
dtostrf(amps, 2, 1, camps);
String sruntime = String(cruntime);
sruntime.trim();
String samps = String(camps);
samps.trim();
String cwpdata = "serial=test&runtime=" + sruntime + "&amps=" + samps; // posted to server
```

I've check my server for errors, but couldn't find records of these. Is there anyway I can see what is being posted each time so I can see where the request is not forming properly?

Here is the code in the Arduino to post data:

```
void postData(String inputData, String filename) {
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("POST /dev/telemetry/test/" + filename + ".php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.SERVER.com"); // changed for privacy
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.print("Content-Length: "); 
    client.println(inputData.length()); 
    Serial.println(inputData);
    Serial.print("Data Length: ");
    Serial.println(inputData.length());
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println(); 
    client.println(inputData);
    client.println();
  } // close if client

  wdt_reset();
  unsigned long startMillis = millis();
  unsigned long endMillis = startMillis + timeout;
  while(client.connected() && (millis() < endMillis)) {
    wdt_reset();
    while(client.available()) {
      char ch = client.read();
      Serial.print(ch);
      wdt_reset();
    } 
  }
  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  Serial.println();
  client.stop();
  int memory = freeMemory();
  if (memory < 125) {
    delay(15000);
  }
}
```

Comment: There should be an error.log somewhere on your server.

Comment: I've looked in all the error logs I've found and didn't see it. I'll look again.

Comment: I've looked again through all the error logs in that folder and the folders above and found nothing. I looked through the raw server log and there is no 400 showing up.

Comment: Your code lacks the important part: How do you send the data to the server?

Comment: @MikeCAT I added the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would hazard a guess that, sometimes, your `inputData` contains unescaped characters that are not properly encoded before they are sent in the POST body.

Within `"serial=test&runtime=" + sruntime + "&amps=" + samps`, if either `sruntime` or `samps` contains unescaped characters, it could very well throw the server-side parsing off. Are there any "unprintable" control bytes hiding in the `Serial.println(inputData)` that might have been overlooked?

"Safe" characters, by the way, are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, dash, underscore, dot, tilde, and the plus sign (which means space). Everything else would have to be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) before being sent. It gets a [little hairier](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm) if the data happens to be Unicode.

Comment: I think you may be right. One time I caught a space in the inputData, that is why I added the trim() command, but that didn't always work, either. This irks me about C is that it is so complex to change data to strings, and all sorts of stuff happens under the hood.